# Python, redirecting the stream of Popen to a python function

Tags: python, stream, subprocess, yield, popen

I'm new to python programming.
I have this problem: I have a list of text files (both compressed and not) and I need to :
- connect to the server and open them 
- after the opening of the file, I need to take his content and pass it to another python function that I wrote

```
def readLogs (fileName):
f = open (fileName, 'r')
inStream = f.read()
counter = 0
inStream = re.split('\n', inStream) # Create a 'list of lines'
out = ""              # Will contain the output
logInConst = ""       # log In Construction
curLine = ""          # Line that I am working on

for nextLine in inStream:
    logInConst += curLine  
    curLine = nextLine
    #   check if it is a start of a new log && check if the previous log is 'ready'
    if newLogRegExp.match(curLine) and logInConst != "":

        counter = counter + 1

        out = logInConst
        logInConst = ""
        yield out

yield logInConst + curLine

def checkFile (regExp, fileName):
    generatore = readLogs(fileName)
    listOfMatches=[]

    for i in generatore: #I'm now cycling through the logs
        # regExp must be a COMPILE regular expression
        if regExp.search(i):
            listOfMatches.append(i)
    return listOfMatches
```

in order to elaborate the info contained in those files.
The function has the aim of write in just 1 line the logs that are stored in those files using 3 lines ... The function is working fine on files read from my local machine but I cannot figure out how to connect to a remote server and create these one-line logs without storing the content of each file into a string and then working with the string ... The command that I use to connect to the remote machine is :

```
connection_out = Popen(['ssh', retList[0], 'cd '+retList[2]+'; cat'+fileName], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

retList[0] and retList[2] are the user@remote and the folder name that I have to access

Thanks to all in advance !

**UPDATE:**

My problem is that I have to establish an ssh connection first :

```
pr1=Popen(['ssh', 'siatc@lgssp101', '*~/XYZ/AAAAA/log_archive/00/MSG_090308_162648.gz*' ], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

All the files that I need to open are stored in a list, fileList[], part of them are compressed (.gz) and part are just text files !! I have tried all the procedures that u showed before bot nothing worked ... I think that I mus modify the third argument of the Popen function but I cannot figure out how to do it ! Is there anyone that can help me ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have to split the stream/file into lines yourself. Just iterate:

```
for ln in f:
    # work on line in ln
```

This should work equally well for files (using open() for file()) and pipes (using Popen). Use the `stdout` property of the popen object to access the pipe connected to stdout of the subprocess

**Example**

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
pp = Popen('dir', shell=True, stdout=PIPE)

for ln in pp.stdout:
    print '#',ln
```

Comment: I really don't understand, I should write something like 
for nextLine in Popen(['ssh', retList[0], 'cd '+retList[2]+'; cat'+fileName], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]

in the most external FOR of the function readLogs ???

Comment: Use the stdout attribute to access the pipe. communicate will not help here. I have updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Remove InStream and just use the file object.

So that your code would read:

```
for nextLine in f.readlines():
    .
    .
    .
```

Ber has it right.

To clarify, the default iteration behavior of a file object is to return the next line. so "**for nextLine in f**" will give you the same results as "**for nextLine in f.readlines()**".

See the file object documentation for details: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something via ssh, why not use [the Python SSH module](http://pyssh.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this page, best info on popen I have found so far....

http://jimmyg.org/blog/2009/working-with-python-subprocess.html